# Android - Set up Google Play Services and Firebase - Gradle build error

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, google-play-services

I'm having issues including Google services in my project.

**The errors**

Following [these](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#split) instructions, and also referring to the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client) to set it up, I encounter a problem with the `apply plugins` property:
[image: Gradle error]
For reasons unbeknownst to me, it's not fetching correctly (something about the version being wrong) even though that property is **auto-filled** when you click on 'Add FCM to your app' (in purple). And as you can see, it doesn't have any version numbers in the URL.
I also encounter a problem with the `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.1.0'` property.

I'll add in my manifest and gradle files for reference:

*AndroidManifest.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="com.nationscompanies.uordermobile">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_descriptor">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service
            android:name=".MyAndroidFirebaseMessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service
            android:name=".MyAndroidFirebaseInstanceIdService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

*build.gradle* (Project)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

*build.gradle* (app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.nationscompanies.uordermobile"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    api 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:15.0.1'
    api 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    api 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' // this is the line that gets autofilled when you click on the 'Add FCM to your app' button from Firebase manager
```

*Full error message*

**Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 15.0.1.**

And then a giant list of errors:
[image: mega-huge error list]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'
```

into this:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.2'
```

to prevent from getting the version conflict error.

Check here for more info:

https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/05/announcing-new-sdk-versioning.html

> Beginning with version 15 of all Play services and Firebase libraries, each Maven dependency matching `com.google.android.gms:play-services-*` and `com.google.firebase:firebase-*` is no longer required to have the same version number in order to work correctly at build time and at run time.
>
> In order to support this change in versioning, the Play services Gradle plugin has been updated to `3.0.0`(which is the first version).